# How to write a list of values to text file with strings and numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a 3 lists :

```
AList = ['name','name2']
BList = ['desg1','desg2']
InList = [1,2]
```

I am writing it to a text file using the follo code snippet:

```
fo = open(filepath, "w")
for i in zip(AList,BList,InList):
     lines=fo.writelines(','.join(i) + '\n')
```

but i am getting the follo error:

```
TypeError: sequence item 2: expected string, int found
```

How can i write the values to text file with new line character.

Comment: what's your expected output in the file?

Comment: @AshishRanjan name,desg1,1   \n                                                                           name1,desg2,2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`join` expects a sequence of `str` items as first argument, but your `InList` contains `int` values. Just convert them to a `str`:

```
lines=fo.writelines(','.join(map(str, i)) + '\n')
```

I'd suggest you to use `with` block while working with files. You could also write all your lines in a single statement:

```
with open(filepath, "w") as fo:
    fo.writelines(','.join(map(str, x)) + '\n' for x in zip(AList,BList,InList))
```

Answer (score 1):

`join` expects string items but you've int in the InList. So either convert them to string before using join or you can do it like this :

```
AList = ['name','name2']
BList = ['desg1','desg2']
InList = ['1','2']

fo = open("a.txt", "w")
for i in range(len(AList)):
    dataToWrite = ",".join((AList[i], BList[i], str(InList[i]))) + '\n'
    lines=fo.writelines(dataToWrite)
```